# Python writing to text-file does not work sometimes

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that writes log-texts into a text-file:

```
from time import strftime, localtime

def log(Text):
    with open("Log.txt", 'a') as log_file:
        log_file.write(strftime('%H:%M:%S',localtime()) + ' -- ' + Text + '\n')
```

On the first run, when Log.txt is not yet created, this code works: it creates a file with called 'Log.txt' and when I open it I can see the text that I gave as input.

After that however it doesn't work anymore. When this file exists and I give a new text as input to write to it, it does not do that. I also checked the time of last modification of the file itself: the code doesn't even touch the text-file, since the modicification time remains the same.

I hope someone shows what's wrong here.

Regards, Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I define multiple paths in the code where certain files have to be saved (DataFrames and images). Somehow, the code puts the Log-file in the dictionary currently open, so the Log-file was spread over these folder-paths with bits of pieces of information.

I solved this by defining a path for the Log-file itself:

```
def log(Text):
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    with open(current_dir + "\\" + "Log.txt", 'a') as log_file:
        log_file.write(strftime('%H:%M:%S',localtime()) + ' -- ' + Text + '\n')
```

Now the current dictionary is always the same and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If your code worked before saving the txt file, I'm not sure but, because I had a problem simulating yours, take a look at your txt file and see if there was any change in the file format, **UTF-8**  or similar.  Perhaps this is the reason for the problem.  Hope this helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfect, I test it in 2 ways:

1st way: example1.py :

```
from time import strftime, localtime

def log(Text):
    with open("Log.txt", 'a') as log_file:
        log_file.write(strftime('%H:%M:%S',localtime()) + ' -- ' + Text + '\n')


log("Hello world!")
```

I just change the message added at the last line every time I test it.

2nd way: example2.py :

```
from time import strftime, localtime

def log(Text):
    with open("Log.txt", 'a') as log_file:
        log_file.write(strftime('%H:%M:%S',localtime()) + ' -- ' + Text + '\n')

while True:
    try:
        info = input("enter your information: ")
        log(info)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

input("\nEnter to close")
```

In this case I add information to the .txt file many times without closing the python script using exceptions and KeyboardInterrupt to close the python script. It works fine too.

Be sure to use your script having closed the previous same script because could exists a files conflict problem. specially when you are using *open()* funcion.